# How to get the drop down box value without submitting in php

Tags: php, database, drop-down-menu

how to get the drop down box value when it is selected and how to retrieve values from database accordingly,without submitting the form.

Answer (score 1):

You find the selected option with javascript and retrieve values with ajax if they are so dynamic

Answer (score 0):

All this can be done using javascript (ajax)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that is possible, at least not in PHP.